# How to choose best board/move?

Tags: python, function, chess

I need help on a introductory python programming assignment for a hexapawn game. I need to write a function that needs to arguments (the computer's pawn and the list of possible boards/moves). I've written the function that generates the list of possible boards (all_boards) which returns a list that contains all possible moves the program can make.

So far I have a function that goes through each board and counts the numbers of pawns the program has and the number of pawns the "user" has and save them to a list. What I need help is using these numbers to choose the best board by seeing which board has the greatest number of program pawns when compared to the user's pawns and returns the best board. Additionally I would also like to determine the best board if the program captures all user pawns or reaches the end of the board (i.e. moves that mean the program wins the game)

Here is the code I currently have so-far:

```
def BestMoves(pawn,all_boards):
    COMPAWNS = []
    USERPAWNS = []
    if pawn == 1:
        opponent = 2
    elif pawn == 2:
        opponent = 1
    # loop starts
    for board in all_boards:
        computercount=[]
        usercounter=[]
        computerpawn = 0
        userpawn = 0

        for i in range(len(board)):

            for j in range(len(board[0])):

                piece = board[i][j]
                if piece == pawn:
                    computerpawn = computerpawn + 1
                if piece == opponent:
                    userpawn = userpawn + 1

        computercount.append(computerpawn)
        usercounter.append(userpawn)
        COMPAWNS.append(computercount)
        USERPAWNS.append(usercounter)

    print("User Pawns:",USERPAWNS)
    print("Computer Pawns:",COMPAWNS)
```

Example of what it should basically do:

```
>>>BestMove(1,[[[0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 2], [2, 0, 2]], [[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2], [2, 0,2]], [[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [2, 0, 2]]])  
 [[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [2, 0, 2]]
```

Comment: Does "1" mean my pawn and "2", a pawn of the opponent and you need to pick the position with the biggest number or 2 or you just need to find a way to win the game. In that case, you just need to build the tree of all possible movements and search for winning movements?

Comment: 1 = white pawns and 2=black pawns (either can happen depending on input from the main program). I need to return the best board that takes into account the greatest number of program pawns or see if any boards allows the program to win.

Comment: Ways to win: 1. you reach the end of the board (any sized board nxn) 2. you capture all opponent pawns or 3. opponent cannot move his pawns (i.e pawns can only move forward or diagonally if opponent is in the space)

Comment: `return max(list_of_boards, key=func_that_determines_how_good_the_board_is)`  Or am I not going in the right direction?

Comment: Without taking care of the context of the game, does it mean: 
"Either, returning a position, where there is no user pawn if any. 
Or, returning the postion with the maximal number of computer pawns (and if they are many, return the position with the minimal number of user pawns)? "

Comment: The minimum board evaluation for this assignment is just comparing the number of pawns on the board and returning the board that contains most of the program's pawn (i.e. difference between program and user pawns). Better evaluations would take account of if the program's pawns reach the end of the board or capture all the opponent's pawns (in the list of possible boards)